# Comparison of various approaches to set locale in the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

The official [Rails I18n documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setup-the-rails-application-for-internationalization) suggests 3 approaches to set the locale in your URL.

1. Subdomain - `ja.example.com`
2. Route namespacing - `www.example.com/ja/users/2`
3. Query paramater - `www.example.com/users/2?locale=ja`

All 3 of these have various advantages and disadvantages. Which do you use in your personal apps, and which have hidden maintenance and development costs?

Are there any other options to set the locale?

Thanks!